# rust-analyzer.linkedProjects doesn't work with relative path, ${workspaceFolder}. Is there any workaround?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

- I have a repository that has a Cargo.toml in `sub_dir/Cargo.toml`
  (Cargo.toml is not in repository root directory)
- I'm using the repository from some of my computers. So I need to set up `rust-analyzer.linkedProjects` by each environment...

I want to avoid the configuration by machine.
Do you know anything workaround?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to `.vscode/settings.json`, should add the path to Cargo.toml, like this.

```
// correct
"rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": [
  "relateive/path/to/the/project/directory/Cargo.toml",
]

// incorrect
"rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": [
  "relateive/path/to/the/project/directory",
]
```

Comment: I spent so much time on this. The wording of the error message is really bad.

Answer (score 1):

In `.vscode/settings.json` set the `"rust-analyzer.linkedProjects"` point to your `Cargo.toml` using an **absolute** path. That's the only way I got it to work eventhough all the resources online tend to tell you to use a *relative* path.

```json
"rust-analyzer.linkedProjects": [
  "absolute/path/to/the/project/Cargo.toml"
],
```

Comment: I had to use a absolute path as well. For example in your .vscode/settings.json you would put "backend/rust_project/Cargo.toml" for a a tree structure as backend->rust_project from the root folder.